# Unable to open .ics file in Android Google Calendar

Tags: android, icalendar

I am trying to manually generate .ics for some events. The file is opening on windows outlook and calendar, but when I try to open this file in the mobile version of google calendar, it is saying "unable to open file". Can someone tell me what is wrong with this file?

**Content of File:**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
X-LOTUS-CHARSET:UTF-8
PRODID:-//Adarsh Test Calendar
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:c8d1a181-3bc1-4efb-8d73-1cabdd4cd42f
CATEGORIES:None
CLASS:
SUMMARY:Flight from Singapore to Hong Kong 
DESCRIPTION:SQ Singapore Airlines SQ894 Economy class
LOCATION:Singapore \, Singapore Changi Airport \, 
PRIORITY:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTART:20220507T050500
DTEND:20220508T090500
TRANSP:OPAQUE
CREATED:20220418T165905Z
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;VALUE=DURATION:-PT24H
DESCRIPTION:Do not forget to check-in for your flight
END:VALARM

END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ff559bcb-4468-4886-86a1-27777850b07a
CATEGORIES:None
CLASS:
SUMMARY:Flight from Chennai to Singapore 
DESCRIPTION:6E IndiGo Airlines 6E112    Economy class
LOCATION:Chennai \, Chennai International Airport \, 
PRIORITY:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTART:20220429T220000
DTEND:20220429T213000
TRANSP:OPAQUE
CREATED:20220418T165905Z
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;VALUE=DURATION:-PT24H
DESCRIPTION:Do not forget to check-in for your flight
END:VALARM

END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include ORGANIZER when using METHOD:PUBLISH ([source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446#section-3.2.1))

I've been struggling with this same issue for like 2 hours. The calendar app on my Mac opened it just fine (apparently more lenient on formatting). Google and Samsung, however, would not open.